# How to render own view instead of Active camera in after effects

Tags: after-effects, animation-rendering

How can I render my own View `Eigene Ansicht 1` instead of the Active Camera `Aktive Kamera` in Adobe After Effects? Take a look at the picture to understand my question.

[image]

My problem is, if I render my movie, the camera view is wrong and my whole movie is showing from a wrong perspective because I worked on `Eigene Ansicht 1` to whole time and not on `Aktive Kamera`.

Comment: Seems not possible but there's a workaround suggested [here](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/790053?tstart=0).